# Why can't I export an APK from my project in Game Maker?

Tags: android, game-maker

I'm already extremely tired, it's already hours and more hours seeing tutorials and none of my problem is minimally solved.

I have already set everything in global game settings (I believe there may be some mistake):

[image]

The keystore is okay:

[image]

There is the android sdk manager:

[image]

But when I'm going to create the application:

[image]

Compile window:

```js
Create started: 21:14:15
"D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\Desktop\Downloads\GameMaker Studio Master Collection 1.4.1760\GameMaker-Studio\GMAssetCompiler.exe" /fU="D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_79013\a84237.txt" /c /m=android   /config="Default" /tgt=8 /obob=True /obpp=False /obru=True /obes=False /i=3 /j=4 /cvm /tp=1024 /mv=1 /iv=0 /rv=0 /bv=1760 /gn="5im" /td="D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\AppData\Local" /cd="D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\Documents\GameMaker\Cache" /sh=True /dbgp="6502" /hip="192.168.25.5" /hprt="51268" /optionsini="D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_79013\gm_ttt_37812\5im.ini" /o="D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_79013\gm_ttt_37812" "D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\Desktop\Genesys Generation\Projetos\Projeto Jogos\Projeto 5im\5im.gmx\5im.project.gmx"

Reading project file....finished.
Compile Constants...finished.
Remove DnD...finished.
Compile Scripts...finished.
Compile Objects...finished.
Compile Timelines...finished.
Compile Triggers...finished.
Compile Rooms...finished.
Compile Extensions...finished.
Global scripts...finished.
Final Compile...finished.
Saving IFF file... D:\Usu�rios\Boneco Sinforoso\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_79013\gm_ttt_37812\5im.droid
Writing Chunk... GEN8
Writing Chunk... OPTN
Writing Chunk... LANG
Writing Chunk... EXTN
Writing Chunk... SOND
Writing Chunk... AGRP
Writing Chunk... SPRT
Writing Chunk... BGND
Writing Chunk... PATH
Writing Chunk... SCPT
Writing Chunk... GLOB
Writing Chunk... SHDR
Writing Chunk... FONT
Writing Chunk... TMLN
Writing Chunk... OBJT
Writing Chunk... ROOM
Writing Chunk... DAFL
Writing Chunk... TPAGE
Writing Chunk... CODE
Writing Chunk... VARI
Writing Chunk... FUNC
Writing Chunk... STRG
Writing Chunk... TXTR
0 Compressing texture... writing texture texture_0.png... 
Writing Chunk... AUDO
Writing Chunk... SCPT
Writing Chunk... DBGI
Writing Chunk... INST
Writing Chunk... LOCL
Writing Chunk... STRG
Stats : GMA : Elapsed=1359
Stats : GMA : sp=22,au=0,bk=1,pt=0,sc=0,sh=0,fo=0,tl=0,ob=2,ro=2,da=0,ex=0,ma=2,fm=0xC100060
cmd /c "subst Z: "D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\5im\Android\Default" && Z: && cd \com.GG.S5in && "D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\Desktop\Downloads\GameMaker Studio Master Collection 1.4.1760\GameMaker-Studio\Android\runner\gradle\gradlew"  assembleRelease lint "

Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-24' in inconsistent location 'c:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24-1' (Expected 'c:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24')
Already observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-24' in 'c:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24'. Skipping duplicate at 'c:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24-1'
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:com.GG.S5in:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:checkReleaseManifest
:com.GG.S5in:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:prepareReleaseDependencies
:com.GG.S5in:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:mergeReleaseAssets
:com.GG.S5in:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:processArmeabi-v7aReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:processArmeabi-v7aReleaseResources
:com.GG.S5in:processArmeabiReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:processArmeabiReleaseResources
:com.GG.S5in:processMipsReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:processMipsReleaseResources
:com.GG.S5in:processUniversalReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:processUniversalReleaseResources
:com.GG.S5in:processX86ReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:processX86ReleaseResources
:com.GG.S5in:generateReleaseSources
:com.GG.S5in:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:prePackageMarkerForRelease
:com.GG.S5in:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:collectReleaseMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:transformClassesWithDexForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:com.GG.S5in:validateReleaseSigning FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':com.GG.S5in:validateReleaseSigning'.
> Keystore file D:\Usu?rios\Boneco Sinforoso\AppData\Local\gamemaker_studio\keystore.keystore not found for signing config 'release'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.136 secs
cmd /c "subst /d Z:"

Lint Build report available at D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\5im\Android\Default\com.GG.S5in\build\outputs\lint-results.html
Create finished: 21:14:25
```

I do not know what else to do. I have already changed the target sdk, min sdk, compile sdk, and nothing. I do not know where else to go, and yoyogames does not give me any really useful information, anyway ... I'm sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Does "D:\Usuários\Boneco Sinforoso\AppData\Local\gamemaker_studio\keystore.keystore" exist? If it does, I suspect the problem might be that it's having trouble with the letter 'á'.

Comment: Yes, the directory exists. What do you advise me to do?

Comment: Try changing the 'á ' in 'Usuários' to a regular 'a' if possible, to ensure that isn't the problem.

Comment: `File` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Asset Cache directory`, change it to `D:\Cache`.

Comment: In addition to `á` char (and any other outside ASCII with codes 32-127), spaces also may be cause of different problems (may be, but also may be not). For example: `Boneco Sinforoso`, `GameMaker Studio Master Collection 1.4.1760`, etc.

Comment: The solution I found was to make a copy of the keystore to any directory that did not contain any "special" characters. Build Successful!!! I also did what he suggested and I directed `to D: \`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment in the question itself, the problem happened because of the **keystore directory**.

In the preferences I changed the directory to one that is practically in the root (**C:\Android\sdk\myKeystore**). So that way I avoid directories that contain words with accents, spaces, or invalid characters.

[image]

With this I was able to successfully export the APK.

Answer (score 1):

Your Support lib must be the same level as the target SDK, so if you target SDK 25 your support library must be the latest related to 25, say 25.0.0 or other similar like 25.0.1

Also the name of the app in the package name must be the same from Display name